# Passing data from one class to another class

Tags: java, android, package

I am developing a utility class in Android 2.2 exposing various methods to Application.
Application can import my jar file(utility class) to invoke methods defined in utility class. Can somebody tell me how to pass/return data to application class from my utility class. 
Note: utility class and application class is kept under different packages.

Comment: check this one: http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: If your utility class is passive you can make a library otherwise, its possible to have two packages in one app.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please have a look.

Comment: I achieved this using "Handler" class. Than you all for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to use class of any other package in your current class then you will have to import that package in your class and then create object of its class and call its function.

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html

EDIT: i found a same type of question :
[Using utility classes in the android programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930248/using-utility-classes-in-the-android-programming)

It heavily depends on what kind of utility you're referring to. There are

1) utility classes that implement static methods. In that case you just call them directly using class name

2) utility classes methods that are not static - requires creating and possibly initializing an instance of that class. Then the instance is used to call those methods.

3) utility classes that can be accessed thru Context. then you can call getApplicationContext() and then you can get access to the utility classes

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I have a utility class having methods. I want to return/pass output data asynchornously to the application which had called my methods.

Comment: @Vidhya: it would be more helpful if you could paste related code. so that people can see exact situation and provide you better solution .

Comment: Could you pls refer to the below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883079/usage-of-sendbroadcast