# Usage of sendBroadcast()

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

sendBroadcast() - Should it be called inside Activity?
I am trying to call sendBroadcast() from my method of utility-class which doesn't extend Activity. I am getting compilation error as below

> The method sendBroadcast(Intent) is
>   undefined for the type MyWrapperClass
>   MyWrapperClass.java

Here is the code snippet:

```
abstract class MyWrapperClass {

    public static void sendData()
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent ("com.proj.utility.mgr",null);

             intent.putExtra("example","Broadcasting "); 

            sendBroadcast(intent);

         }
    }
```

Is there any concept behind using sendBroadcast call inside my class. There is no issue in using sendBroadcast() inside Activity. 
Can someone here help me to resolve it? 
Or Any other suggestions are invited to return data from utility class to application asynchronously.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need access to the application context to call sendbroadcast. Could you not get this information from android documentnation.

Answer (score 25):

You should pass the context from activity class to utility class to access the specific application resources like startActivity, sendBroadcast, etc.

```
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you extend Application object (main entry that is being called before the your first Activity) then you can keep a shared singletone for your application.