# How to send a broadcast in recyclerview adapter class?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-recyclerview

I have a **RecyclerView** which displays all songs found on the device.

**Adapter class**

```
holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Store songList and songIndex in mSharedPreferences
            storageUtil.storeSong(Main.musicList);
            storageUtil.storeSongIndex(holder.getAdapterPosition());

            //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
            Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
            sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);

            Intent broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_SONG);
            sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong);
        }
    });
```

What i want to achieve is that when a song is clicked in the **RecyclerView** a **Broadcast** is send to my **Service class** so a song starts playing.

sendBroadcast cannot be resolved, so how do i send a broadcast intent from my adapter class?

I also would like to know if this is a right way to do it or if there is a better way to send a broadcast in the adapter because i read somewhere **BroadcastReceivers** don't belong in the adapter class.

Comment: This might help to do it the right way 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883079/usage-of-sendbroadcast

Comment: @Kaveri How can I send the broadcast receiver while sending ad reciving a message in my recyclerview list. (i.e) I have a chat screen, I can send message, but it not received by the receiver when I am sending the message. Need to go back and forth to see the new message. (I need to receive the message in real time as whatsapp.) How can I update my recyclerview for the sender adnder and receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** [sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) is a method of `Context` class, because you call it in `Adapter` class, that why the compiler shows the error "sendBroadcast cannot be resolved".

**Solution:** Obtain context from a view instance then call `sendBroadcast` method.

```
holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Store songList and songIndex in mSharedPreferences
        storageUtil.storeSong(Main.musicList);
        storageUtil.storeSongIndex(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        // Obtain context from view instance.
        Context context = v.getContext();

        //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
        Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);

        Intent broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_SONG);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong);
    }
});
```