# Android static utility class

Tags: android, class, static, utility

I'm trying to create a static utility class which will contain simple functions like Messagebox(AlertDialog), EmailSender,  etc... and will call these functions on other activites.
But as I understand I can not create a static class if it is not in a class.
What do you suggest for this kind of utility classes?

Comment: what about using a Singleton? I frequently use this pattern if I want to have statefull shared functionalities among different activities.

Comment: Can you give an example please.

Comment: What you should do is to create a singleton properly by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: right way to create utility class http://stackoverflow.com/a/31581218/3496570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make it that way

```
class Utils{
    public static void makeToast(Context context, String text){
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In your activity call it this way

```
Utils.makeToast(this,"hi");
```

Comment: A better approach for a utilities class is to make the class `final` and add a `private` constructor.